# getting object from the main and manipulate C++

Tags: c++

So i want to manipulate an object given in the main, i was wondering if if it's possible that i create a class that takes a reference to that particular object, so that i can manipulate it and changes the original object too.

```
Result(std::vector<Foo> &foo2):foo(foo2){}
```

The above code will be the constructor for my `result` class and `foo2`  is an object created in the main that i initialize to the local vector `foo`. Will this work? if not why? This is only one of my 2k lines of code (and many classes).  This question will actually answer lots of my other question about c++.

Comment: This question is completely incomprehensible.

Comment: Yes this will work, however you must be very careful to make sure that the argument provided stays alive and in the same memory location, so long as a `Result` is referring to it. Otherwise the `Result` will hold a dangling reference.

Comment: @M.M looks like an answer!

Comment: @M.M Do you think it's bad programming or it's actually ok?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was able to understand the question.

Comment: Can you pass the object as a parameter to the functions that need to work on it?

Comment: So, Result is derived off foo which is constructed from a reference to a vector of foos.  Do I understand that correctly?
How can a foo be constructed from multiple foos?

Comment: Don't write 2000 lines of code before you know the first 1000 lines work. Don't write 1000 lines of code before you know the first 500 work. Don't write 500 lines of code before....

Comment: Everything is working perfectly sir!

Comment: @NeilKirk to answer you question, no i can't directly, so that's why i create a class so i will have  `get` method to return that `vector` which will allow me to manipulate that in other classes

Answer (score -1):

If that is your constructor it will take the value in by reference.  After that it will actually call the copy constructor of vector, and copy foo2 into foo so that any changes you make to foo will not be reflected in the original foo2.  If you want to store something from main as a member of a class you should use pointers.

```
std::vector<Foo>* foo; // member pointer
...
Result(std::vector<Foo>* foo2):foo(foo2){}
```

Comment: It depends on whether `foo` is a reference or not. We can't tell from the given code.

Comment: `foo` can't be define as reference in my case, because from what i know i have to initialize all reference at compile time and in my case i don't know the vector that `foo` will receive until `run` time

Comment: @Bobby References are bound at runtime, they just cannot rebind after creation.